# Unable to fetch data from GET operation after POST on "https://httpbin.org/"

Tags: c#, json, post, httpclient, fiddler

I am trying to perform a POST operation on "https://httpbin.org/anything". Post that when I try to do GET operation, it returns me empty data.

However, If I try to do same operation on Fiddler, it returns the data which I have added in POST.
Unable to understand this difference between fiddler and programmatic approach.

Here's my code:

```
  static async Task Main()
    {
        _clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            UseCookies = true
        };

        HttpClientTest = new HttpClient(_clientHandler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://httpbin.org/") };

        ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass
        {
            ID = "1",
            Username = "RK"
        };

        var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelClass);
        var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var postRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://httpbin.org/anything"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = content
        };

        var postResponse = await HttpClientTest.SendAsync(postRequest);
        postResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var jsonPost = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var postResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonPost);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://httpbin.org/anything"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        };

        var response = await HttpClientTest.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var searchResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        var searchResponse1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelClass>(json);
    }
```

> Output of POST operation:

```
    {{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"ID\":\"1\",\"Username\":\"RK\"}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "26",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-60c34be2-551f6226276690a54470861c"
  },
  "json": {
    "ID": "1",
    "Username": "RK"
  },
  "method": "POST",
  "origin": "",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}}
```

> Output of GET()

```
{{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-60c34bf6-392b2ca3286cdcfd4f8ef9c9"
  },
  "json": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "origin": "",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/anything"
}}
```

Comment: Do you get a 200 OK status or a 400/500 Error code?

Comment: @jdweng 200 OK status

Comment: If data is null then the server did not put any body into the response.

Comment: @jdweng When I submit Post Request, response contains data i.e. id:1 and name:RK". However after that when I do GET(), it returns empty data

Comment: @jdweng Have updated the question with response output. Check "data":

Comment: You send a request from client to server and then server sends a response from server to client.  The difference between a Get and a Post is the Post has a body (or json) while the Get has not body (or json is null/empty).  You did not capture the response from the server to client.  You are having issues with the response not the request.

Comment: @jdweng Isn't this line captures the GET response `var response = await HttpClientTest.SendAsync(request);` last 5 lines of code.

Comment: Yes.  But it is not what you posted.  What you posted are the two requests from client to server.  What you are receiving is the response from server to client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233651/discussion-between-raj-and-jdweng).

Comment: I can't do a chat.

Comment: You have included the POST result received from the server but the more important part is the request. If you want to understand the differences between your request and the one created by Fiddler simply redirect your code to use Fiddler as proxy. Then you can inspect both requests and see how they are different.